# Override ToString in a Windows Runtime Component

Tags: c++, win-universal-app, c++-cx

I've created a Windows Runtime Component (namespace: Animal) and I want override the Platform::String::ToString method.

Dog.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Animal
{
    public ref struct Dog sealed
    {
    private:
        String^ _name; // Yes, it's private
    public:
        Dog();
        //String^ ToString();
        virtual String^ ToString() override { } // I've found this in internet
    };
}
```

Dog.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Dog.h"

using namespace Animal;
using namespace Platform;

String^ _name;
Dog::Dog()
{
}
String^ Dog::ToString()
{
    return _name;
}
```

And all the compiling errors are in Dog.h in "virtual String^ ToString() override { }":

```
· Error C2433 'Animal::Dog::String': 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
· Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support · default-int
· Error C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '^'
· Error C2334 unexpected token(s) preceding '{', skipping apparent function body
```

Comment: Use Platform::String in your .h file so you don't depend on `using namespace Platform;` to be in scope.  And fix the bugs in your .cpp file.

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question. The question goes in the question. Answers go in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your derived class:

```
virtual String^ ToString() override
{
    return _name;
}
```

Edit:

Do you still have the `{ }` braces at the end of the `ToString()` declaration in the header file?  If so, then you've already defined the method body.  So the compiler will complain about the redefinition in the .cpp file.

Comment: I've tried that in Dog.h and Dog.cpp and a lot of more variations. Same errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

1. Delete the ToString() method in Dog.cpp
2. Replace "String" by "Platform::String" in Dog.cpp and Dog.h
3. Add "virtual Platform::String^ ToString() override { return _name; };" in Dog.h.